# Spark computation for suggesting new friendships

Tags: python, performance, mapreduce, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using Spark for fun and to learn new things about MapReduce. So, I'm trying to write a program suggesting new friendships (i.e., a sort of recommendation system). The suggestion of a friendship between two individuals is performed if they are not connected yet and have a lot of friends in common.

The friendship text file has a structure similar to the following:

```
1   2,4,11,12,15
2   1,3,4,5,9,10
3   2,5,11,15,20,21
4   1,2,3
5   2,3,4,15,16
...
```

where the syntax is: `ID_SRC1<TAB>ID_DST1,ID_DST2,...`.

The program should output (print or text file) something like the following:

```
1   3,5
3   1
5   1
...
```

where the syntax is: `ID_SRC1<TAB>ID_SUGG1,ID_SUGG2,...`. Of course the program must suggest a friendship if the two individuals shares a minimum number of friends, let's say `3` in our case.

I've written my program, but I'd like to read better and more powerful solutions by you. Indeed, I think my code can improved a lot since it takes much time to output from an input file of 4.2 MB.

Below my code:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

def linesToDataset(line):
    (src, dst_line) = line.split('\t')
    src = int(src.strip())

    dst_list_string = dst_line.split(',')
    dst_list = [int(x.strip()) for x in dst_list_string if x != '']

    return (src, dst_list)  

def filterPairs(x):
     # don't take into account pairs of a same node and pairs of already friends
    if (x[0][0] != x[1][0]) and (not x[0][0] in x[1][1]) and (not x[1][0] in x[0][1]):
        shared = len(list(set(x[0][1]).intersection(set(x[1][1]))))
        return (x[0][0], [x[1][0], shared])

def mapFinalDataset(elem):
    recommendations = []
    src = elem[0]
    dst_commons = elem[1]
    for pair in dst_commons:
        if pair[1] > 3: # 3 is the minimum number of friends in common
            recommendations.append(pair[0])
    return (src, recommendations)

def main():
    conf = SparkConf().setAppName("Recommendation System").setMaster("local[4]")
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
    rdd = sc.textFile("data.txt")

    dataset = rdd.map(linesToDataset)

    cartesian = dataset.cartesian(dataset)
    filteredDatasetRaw = cartesian.map(filterPairs)
    filteredDataset = filteredDatasetRaw.filter(lambda x: x != None)
#   print filteredDataset.take(10)

    groupedDataset = filteredDataset.groupByKey().mapValues(list)
#   print groupedDataset.take(10)

    finalDataset = groupedDataset.map(mapFinalDataset)
    output = finalDataset.take(100)
    for (k, v) in output:
        if len(v) > 0:
            print str(k) + ': ' + str(v)

    sc.stop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I'd like to know if there are solutions better than mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better is a point of view of course.

I would argue the strategy I am about to propose is better in terms of performance and readability, but this has to be subjective. The main reason is that I avoid the cartesian product, to replace it with a JOIN.

## Alternative strategy

### Description

The strategy I propose is based on the fact that the basic data line

```
1   2,4,11,12,15
```

Can be thought of as a list of "friendship suggestions", meaning this line tells me : "2 should be friends with 4, 11, 12, 15", "4 should be friends with 2, 11, 12, 15", and so on.

Therefore, the gist of my implementation is

1. Turn each line into a list of suggestions (foo should be friends with bar)
2. group suggestions by person (foo should be friends with bar, baz, bar) with duplicates
3. count the number of duplicates (foo should be friends with bar(2 suggestions), baz (1 suggestion)
4. remove existing relationships
5. filter suggestions that occur too rarely
6. print result

### Implementation

As I'm more of a Java/scala guy, pardon the scala language, but it should map fairly easily to Python.

First, create basic friendship data from your text file

```scala
def parseLine(line: String): (Int, Array[String]) = {
  (Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, line.indexOf("\t"))), line.substring(line.indexOf("\t")+1).split(","))
}
def toIntegerArray(strings: Array[String]): Array[Int] = { 
  strings.filter({ x => !x.isEmpty() }).map({ x => Integer.parseInt(x) }) 
}
// The friendships that exist
val alreadyFriendsRDD = sc.textFile("src/data.txt", 4)
        // Parse file : (id of the person, [Int] of friends)
        .map { parseLine }
        .mapValues( toIntegerArray );
```

And convert them to suggestions

```scala
// If person 1 is friends with 2 and 4, this means we should suggest 2 to become friends with 4 , and vice versa
def toSymetricalPairs(suggestions: Array[Int]): TraversableOnce[(Int, Int)] = {
  suggestions.combinations(2)
             .map { suggestion => (suggestion(0), suggestion(1)) }
             .flatMap { suggestion => Iterator(suggestion, (suggestion._2, suggestion._1)) }
}
val suggestionsRDD = alreadyFriendsRDD
  .map( x => x._2 )
  // Then we create suggestions from the friends Array
  .flatMap( toSymetricalPairs )
```

Once you have a RDD of suggestions, regroup them :

```scala
def mergeSuggestion(suggestions: mutable.HashMap[Int, Int], newSuggestion: Int): mutable.HashMap[Int, Int] = {
  suggestions.get(newSuggestion) match {
    case None => suggestions.put(newSuggestion, 1)
    case Some(x) => suggestions.put(newSuggestion, x + 1)
  }
  suggestions
}
def mergeSuggestions(suggestions: mutable.HashMap[Int, Int], toMerge: mutable.HashMap[Int, Int]) = {
  val keySet = suggestions.keySet ++: toMerge.keySet
  keySet.foreach { key =>
    suggestions.get(key) match {
      case None => suggestions.put(key, toMerge.getOrElse(key, 0))
      case Some(x) => suggestions.put(key, x + toMerge.getOrElse(key, 0))
    }
  }
  suggestions
}

def filterRareSuggestions(suggestions: mutable.HashMap[Int, Int]): scala.collection.Set[Int] = {
  suggestions.filter(p => p._2 >= 3).keySet
}

// We reduce as a RDD of suggestion count by person
val suggestionsByPersonRDD = suggestionsRDD.combineByKey(
    // For each person, create a map of suggestion count
    (person: Int) => new mutable.HashMap[Int, Int](),           
    // For every suggestion, merge it into the map
    mergeSuggestion , 
    // When merging two maps, sum the suggestions
    mergeSuggestions
    )
    // We restrict to suggestions that occur more than 3 times
    .mapValues( filterRareSuggestions )
```

Finally filter the suggestions by taking into account already existing friendships

```scala
val suggestionsCleanedRDD = suggestionsByPersonRDD
  // We co-locate the suggestions with the known friends
  .join(alreadyFriendsRDD)
  // We clean the suggestions by removing the known friends
  .mapValues (_ match { case (suggestions, alreadyKnownFriendsByPerson) => {
    suggestions -- alreadyKnownFriendsByPerson
  }})
```

Which outputs, for example :

```
(49831,Set(49853, 49811, 49837, 49774))
(49835,Set(22091, 20569, 29540, 36583, 31122, 3004, 10390, 4113, 1137, 15064, 28563, 20596, 36623))
(49839,Set())
(49843,Set(49844))
```

Meaning 49831 should be friends with 49853, 49811, 49837, 49774.

### Speed

Trying on your dataset, and on a 2012 Corei5@2.8GHz (dual core hyperthread) / 2g RAM, we finish under 1.5 minutes.

Comment: Thank you for your solution GPI. I'd like to better understand your strategy. So, for instance, what happens if we have a case where ``(1, Array(11,12,13)), ..., (30, Array(11,12,13))``?

Comment: How would you define the desired output for your scenario ? I have 2 issues. First, if 1 is friends with 11, I have to assume 11 is friends with 1, right ? Second : is the relationship (11, Array(11, 12, 13)) assumed in your scenario ? If so, I have to assume that the implementation shoud not answer any suggestion.

Comment: 1) Yes, the friendships are mutual, so if 1 is friend with 11, then 11 is friend with 1. 2) The relationship (11, Array(11, 12, 13)) never occurs, i.e., an individual cannot be friend with herself.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. The sample dataset you suggest in your first comment is to be understood as `(1, Array(11,12,13)), ...(11, Array(1, 2, 3, ...10, 12, 13, ... 30), ..., (30, Array(11,12,13))`, right ?

Comment: No no... ``11`` could only be friend with ``1`` and ``30`` for example. So the right tuple is ``(11, Array(1,30))``.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90905/discussion-between-gpi-and-f-ficarola).

Comment: As suggested in some comments, refactored ZIP with a JOIN, which is more readable and makes it easier to work around `zip`'s partitionning requirements