# RDD of integers to all possible pairs (ordered)

Tags: python, pyspark, rdd

I am using pyspark to find all possible pairs from an RDD of int array.

Input:

```
[[0, 1, 2],
[3, 4]]
```

Output RDD key value pairs of all possible combinations:

```
(0,1), (0,2), (1,0), ....  (3,4), (4,3)
```

I want to implement it in python not scala

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark: produce RDD\[(X, X)\] of all possible combinations from RDD\[X\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26557873/spark-produce-rddx-x-of-all-possible-combinations-from-rddx)

Comment: Could you tell us what have you tried? also here is an answer in python: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43703395/1423901

Comment: Most of the solutions are for scala but i want to implement it in python

Comment: This is the solution but it is implemented in scala. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32837588/spark-computation-for-suggesting-new-friendships

Answer (score 0):

[`permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) can be used to used to generate tuples of length 2.

```py
from itertools import permutations

rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([[0, 1, 2],[3, 4]])

rdd.flatMap(lambda x: permutations(x,2)).collect()
```

### Output

```
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (3, 4), (4, 3)]
```